# How to store add params in api url using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

my angular js function code

```
$scope.cardcall = function (cardtype) { 
        $scope.cityname=cityname;   
        $http({method: 'GET',url: '/api/v1/asasas&filterBy=cardNames&filterByValue='+cardtype.key}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.deal = data.deals;              
        });                  
    };
```

my view code

```
<div class="check_box" ng-repeat="cardtype in card.cardTypes.buckets">                                                  
 <label>
 <input type="checkbox" value=" {{cardtype.key}}" name="cardname" ng-click="cardcall(cardtype)" /> {{cardtype.key}} 
 </label>                                                   
</div>
```

now when some click on check box it call api like

```
/api/v1/asasas&filterBy=cardNames&filterByValue=asssas
```

What i am try to make when some one click 2nd check box then api call like

```
/api/v1/asasas&filterBy=cardNames&filterByValue=asssas,xsdza
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `.checked` value to `cardtype` via `ng-model`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cardtype.checked" value=" {{cardtype.key}}" name="cardname" ng-change="typecall()" />
```

Then you could run a loop in your code to determine what's checked

```
$scope.cardcall = function () { 
    $scope.cityname=cityname;

    var keys = [],
        buckets = $scope.card.cardTypes.buckets;

    for (var i = 0, len = buckets.length, i < len; i++) {
        if (buckets[i].checked)
            keys.push(buckets[i].key);
    }

    if (keys.length) {
        keys = keys.join();

        $http({method: 'GET',url: '/api/v1/asasas&filterBy=cardNames&filterByValue=' + keys}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.deal = data.deals;              
        });
    }
};
```

This will be called every time one of those checkboxes gets checked or unchecked and since it looks through all of the checkboxes there's no need to pass `cardtype.key` anymore. If no checkboxes are checked it won't do an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks @DonovanM .But in your code when uncheck then it pass the value and when checked it pass null

Comment: Hmm. Here's what I get in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq4ndwv1/). The key gets logged in the console in this example.

Comment: Hi @DonovanM i Shaw your JSFiddle example it working fine in Angular js 1.1.1 but when i change in to angular js 1.2.1 then it behave like as i mention in my 1st comment.

Comment: It works using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`. I've edited my answer and here's the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uq4ndwv1/1/) working with Angular 1.2.1.